# Vector: Vector properties?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

What does it actually mean when someone say "Vector function **v(t)** has **constant** **magnitude** or **constant direction**." ?

Answer (score 1):

Constant magnitude means $\|v(t)\|$ is constant, constant direction means that for all $t_1,t_2$ the vector $v(t_1)$ is a non-negative multiple of $v(t_2)$.